# SQL Server split counter into 2 parts for same column?

Tags: sql, count, multiple-columns, qsqlquery

After a lot of time wasted trying to get this query to work, I come here to seek for help.

I have a set of data that I want to count. But I want to count into 2 separate columns based on a condition

I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DIM_DATUM](
[DATE_SK] [int] NULL,
[YEAR_NUMBER] [int] NULL,
[MONTH_NUMBER] [int] NULL,
[MONTH_NAME] [varchar](30) NULL,
[HOLIDAY] [varchar](27) NULL) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RIT](
[RideId] [bigint] NULL,
[DATE_SK] [int] NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and im tring to get this output from a query

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>MONTH_NAME</th>
    <th>YEAR_NUMBER</th>
    <th>MONTH_NUMBER</th>
    <th>RidesYES</th>
    <th>RidesNO</th>
    <th>RidesALL</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>JULY</td>
    <td>2017</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>300</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

After a while searching, I could come up with this query that does more or less what I expect

```
SELECT h.HOLIDAY, h.MONTH_NAME, h.YEAR_NUMBER, h.MONTH_NUMBER,
COUNT(CASE WHEN h.HOLIDAY!= 'NO' THEN 1 END) AS RidesYES,
COUNT(CASE WHEN h.HOLIDAY= 'NO' THEN 1 END) AS RidesNO,
COUNT(*) AS RidesALL
FROM FEIT_RIT f
JOIN DIM_DATUM h ON h.DATE_SK = f.DATE_SK
GROUP BY h.HOLIDAY, h.MONTH_NAME, h.YEAR_NUMBER, h.MONTH_NUMBER
ORDER BY h.YEAR_NUMBER, h.MONTH_NUMBER
```

But this is giving me following result back:
[Image of query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu0E3.png)

So basically, I want to have both results of the 2 first rows together in one row while grouping by month or year. Is this possible?
Is this possible with transaction or even a subquery? If so, please help me out!
Thank you in advance

Comment: how about removing holiday in the group by and result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you don't need the `holiday` column. And to get the grouping by `year - month`, group first according to year then month.

```
SELECT h.MONTH_NAME,  h.YEAR_NUMBER, h.MONTH_NUMBER,
COUNT(CASE WHEN h.PUBLIEKE_FEESTDAG != 'NO' THEN 1 END) AS RidesYES,
COUNT(CASE WHEN h.PUBLIEKE_FEESTDAG = 'NO' THEN 1 END) AS RidesNO,
COUNT(*) AS RidesALL
FROM FEIT_RIT f
JOIN DIM_DATUM h ON h.DATE_SK = f.DATE_SK
GROUP BY h.YEAR_NUMBER,  h.MONTH_NAME,  h.MONTH_NUMBER
ORDER BY h.YEAR_NUMBER, h.MONTH_NUMBER
```